# Find $\int_0^\pi \cos^4\theta \sin^3\theta~d\theta$ using de Moivre's theorem

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, trigonometric-integrals

> Find $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \cos^4\theta \sin^3\theta~d\theta$ using de Moivre's theorem.

So I need to find and expression for $\cos^4\theta \sin^3\theta$ in terms of multiple angles. I know that $2\cos\theta = z + z^{-1}$ and $2i\sin\theta = z-z^{-1}$ and my original thought was to work out $\cos^4\theta$ and $\sin^3\theta$ and then multiply my two expressions but I've now realised that this is something I won't be able to easily integrate. In addition to this the expression for $\cos^4\theta \sin^3\theta$ can be expression entirely as multiple angles of $\sin$. This has left me unsure on working out a expression for $\cos^4\theta \sin^3\theta$.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your original thought was correct.  You'll get a combination of powers of $z$, which are easy to integrate.

Comment: Sorry but not using the De Moivre's theorem. 
$$\int_0^{\pi} \sin^3 x\cos^4 x dx=2\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^3 x\cos^4 x dx=B\left(\frac 52,2\right)=\frac {4}{35}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, we have
$$
\cos^4\theta\sin^3\theta=\frac{3\sin\theta + 3 \sin 3\theta - \sin 5\theta - \sin 7\theta}{64}
$$
which you can deduce from de Moivre's $(\cos x+i\sin x)^n=\cos nx+i\sin nx$ and Euler's $e^{ix}=\cos\theta+i\sin x$ or just by repeated product-to-sum. 
 Now integrate from 0 to $\pi$.

Comment: but how did you get the expression for $\cos^4\theta \sin^3\theta$ as that is what I'm stuck on

Comment: Multiply $16\cos^4\theta=(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})^2=e^{i4\theta}+4e^{i2\theta}+6+4e^{-i2\theta}+e^{-i4\theta}$ and $-8i\sin^3\theta=(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})^3=e^{i3\theta}-3e^{i\theta}+3e^{-i\theta}-e^{-i3\theta}$.

Comment: but when i multiply the two things wont i get an expression in terms of cos and sin

Comment: No.  You get $-2^7i\cos^4\theta\sin^4\theta=(e^{i7\theta} - e^{-i7\theta}) + (e^{i5\theta} - e^{-i5\theta}) - 3 (e^{i3\theta} -e^{-i3\theta}) - 3 (e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta})$

Answer (score 0):

Use the properties that
$$\cos^2\theta =\frac{1+\cos2\theta}{2}$$
$$\sin^2\theta=\frac{1-\cos2\theta}{2}$$
$$\cos\theta \sin\alpha= \frac{1}{2} [\sin(\theta+\alpha)+\sin(\theta-\alpha)]$$
$$\cos\theta \cos\alpha= \frac{1}{2} [\cos(\theta+\alpha) +\cos(\theta-\alpha)]$$
$$\sin\theta \sin\alpha= \frac{1}{2} [\cos(\theta-\alpha)-\cos(\theta+\alpha)]$$